# Print Multi-dimensional array using loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I don't understand how to use nested loops(for, foreach,while,dowhile) for printing this multi-dimensional array values in separate lines. I am new in this sector.

Here is the code:

```
    <?php

$bazar = ['vegetables' => ['potato'=>16, 'cucumber'=>40, 'pumpkin'=>30, 'carrot'=>60], 

          'fruit' => ['apples'=> 150, 'pine-apple'=> '50', 'milk' => 100], 

          'fishes' => ['rui'=> 220, 'tuna' => 280, 'shrimp'=> 'it is delicious']
         ];





echo "<pre>";

print_r($bazar);

echo "</pre>";



foreach ($bazar as $net => $values) 
{
  echo $net."<br>";
};

?>
```

Comment: You have to use nested foreach to loop multidimensional array. Use another foreach inside current one to loop through the array $values

Comment: @RobyRajuOommen can you give me a example of it? only loop. It will be great for me to understand

Comment: foreach ($bazar as $net => $values) 
{      echo $net."<br>";    foreach($values as $key => $value){ echo $key." : ".$value;
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have associative array inside associative array
You have to loop the first associative array
and inside it loop the associative array
like this

```
foreach($bazar as $key => $val){

  echo $key.'<br>';
  
  foreach($val as $k => $v){
    echo $k . ' -> ' .$v . '<br>';
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Thnak you again